# Updating session in Remix.run using remix-auth

Tags: javascript, typescript, remix.run

I am using `createCookieSessionStorage` and the `FormStrategy` to authenticate users using `remix-auth` package. I want to update the session data when a user navigates to another page. I have a loader function that handles the routing logic via `return redirect('/pageLocation')`. How do I update the session so that one of the entries becomes `{ firstVisit: true }` from `{ firstVisit: false }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you modify sessions that use cookie storage, you must send the `set-cookie` header along with the response. This includes `redirect`

```js
return redirect(‘/pageLocation’, { headers: { ‘set-cookie’: await commitSession(session) } })
```